# CDK cloud9 - How to attach preconstructed instance profile to Cloud9 instance iam role in cdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk, cloud9-ide, aws-cloud9

I created cloud9 instance and vpc environment via cdk. Also with role permissions and instance profile, how do i attach that at the end via cdk too?

Currently there seem to be no in built parameters about setting iam role in `Ec2Environment`

Can't achieve this automatically too if i use CloudFormation, so i am thinking this is not available yet?

I know i can use custom resource or create a lambda to achieve that, but was thinking it's just a bit too much to just to use to attach an instance profile

My code:

```
const c9IamRole = new iam.Role(this, 'C9IamRole', {
      roleName: 'cloud9-admin-access-role',
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('ec2.amazonaws.com'),
      managedPolicies: [
        iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AdministratorAccess'),
      ]
    });

    const c9InstanceProfile = new iam.CfnInstanceProfile(this, 'C9InstanceProfile', {
      roles: [c9IamRole.roleName],
    });

    // create a cloud9 ec2 environment in a new VPC
    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'VPC', { maxAzs: 3 });
    const c9Env = new cloud9.Ec2Environment(this, 'Cloud9Env', {
      vpc,
      instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T3, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO),
    });
```

IAM role that i want to attach the instance profile (at the created cloud9 ec2 instance page)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Anything using a Cfn prefixed method is an L1 construct. They do not have the hooks necessary to automatically apply them to other constructs (l2 and l3 - the higher level objects) - they are bare bones, just basically a translation from your code to cfn template snippet.

if iam.CfnInstanceProfile does not have a l2 or l3 version (as of this answer it does not seem to, but the CDK team is always updating) then you'll have to manually attach it using other cfn methods.

Also, the cloud9 library is (as of this writing) still Experimental, which is a good indication that it wont have all the things it needs - It does not seem to have any property for attaching a role. You *might* be able to manually (again using cfn escape hatch methods) attach a role.

You might try instead applying the roles to a User/Group and giving them permission to access the cloud9, rather than attaching the role to cloud9 and give allowance to various Identities - it may be easier with current CDK constructs.